# Inserting a default data into MySql

Tags: mysql, json

I know this is a weird and strange thing to want to do, but that's what I am trying to achieve.

I have a MySql database and I wish to have a default data entered into a column of a table in my database, the data is in JSON format:

```
{
  "address":"behindthescene",
  "state":"Slovakia",
  "zip":"56456465",
  "country":"Argentina",
  "city
```

Here's the strange part, my Json is incomplete and needs to be enclosed properly but this is how I want it added.

I configured my table column to use this JSON data as the default value instead of having a null value but when it inserts this as the default value it also completes it hence I now have

```
{
  "address":"behindthescene",
  "state":"Slovakia",
  "zip":"56456465",
  "country":"Argentina",
  "city":""
}
```

This is not what I want, I need it to be in the same exact way I entered the data.

Can anyone guide me on how to get my desired results, do not mind the strangeness of my JSON, I have my reason for wanting it that way.

Comment: Why do you need it without the closing brace? If you really need that value, use/select `replace(myJsonCol, '}', '')` or create a view etc

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean but I have not added the JSON code through PHP, I added it from PHPmyadmin, under structure. The database I was working on was already existent and it has data already.

Comment: MySQL will not accept invalid JSON if you try to use the JSON data type. Your requirement to have fragments of JSON means that you'll have to store it in a TEXT column or something. Frankly, this sounds like an https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @BillKarwin lol, you're spot on with your xyproblem.info ideology, that is exactly me at this point except that I was able to take all the help I've received from you all and pieced it together to solve my problem, I have solved my problem all thanks to your valuable inputs. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the value was set to JSON instead of a CHAR string. If you want it to be incomplete for some reason, just make it a string and stick it in raw.

Comment: Thanks @rebelrae I have solved my problem! 